# How to upgrade Spring 2.56,Hibernate version 3.2.6.ga to 4.0.6 (Spring), 4.3.6.Final(Hibernate)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

We have to update the `spring` , `hibernate` version also we know that we need to update the `maven` and other versions as well .We are using `maven` to bind dependency and making build. I am providing you the all dependency that used in our project.

> [dependency:tree {execution: default-cli}] 
>     com.xyz:web-service:war:0.0  
>     +- com.xyz:core:jar:0.0:compile  
>     |  +- com.xyz:model:jar:0.0:compile  
>     |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile  
>    |  +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.2.2:compile  
>    |  |  - commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.3:compile 
>    |  +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:2.5.6:compile 
>    |  |  - org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:2.5.6:compile 
>    |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:2.5.6:compile 
>    |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:2.5.6:compile 
>    |  +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:2.5.6:compile 
>    |  |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.1:compile 
>    |  |  - org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.6.1:compile 
>    |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core-tiger:jar:2.0.4:compile 
>    |  |  - org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:2.0.4:compile 
>    |  +- org.ow2.jotm:jotm-core:jar:2.1.4:compile 
>    |  |  +- org.ow2.carol:carol:jar:3.0.2:compile 
>    |  |  |  +- org.ow2.carol:carol-interceptors:jar:1.0.1:compile 
>    |  |  |  +- org.ow2.carol.irmi:irmi:jar:1.1.2:compile 
>    |  |  |  +- org.jacorb:jacorb:jar:2.2.3-jonas-patch-20071018:compile 
>    |  |  |  |  - avalon-framework:avalon-framework:jar:4.1.5:compile 
>    |  |  |  +- org.jacorb:jacorb-idl:jar:2.2.3-jonas-patch-20071018:compile 
>    |  |  |  |  - logkit:logkit:jar:1.2:compile 
>    |  |  |  +- org.ow2.cmi:cmi-jndi:jar:2.1.0:compile 
>    |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.util:util-log:jar:1.0.10:compile 
>    |  |  |  |  |  - org.ow2.util:util-i18n:jar:1.0.10:compile 
>    |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.cmi:cmi-api-client:jar:2.1.0:compile 
>    |  |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.util:util-component-api:jar:1.0.10:compile 
>    |  |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.util:util-component-impl:jar:1.0.10:compile 
>    |  |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.util:util-pool-api:jar:1.0.10:compile 
>    |  |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.spec.ee:ow2-ejb-3.0-spec:jar:1.0-M1:compile 
>    |  |  |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.spec.ee:ow2-jta-1.1-spec:jar:1.0-M1:compile 
>    |  |  |  |  |  |  - org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jaxrpc_1.1_spec:jar:1.1:compile 
>    |  |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:servlet-api:jar:6.0.18:compile 
>    |  |  |  |  |  - org.ow2.util:util-event-api:jar:1.0.10:compile 
>    |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.cmi:cmi-rpc:jar:2.1.0:compile 
>    |  |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.cmi:cmi-core-common:jar:2.1.0:compile 
>    |  |  |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.util:util-xmlconfig:jar:1.0.10:compile 
>    |  |  |  |  |  |  - org.ow2.util:util-event-impl:jar:1.0.10:compile 
>    |  |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.cmi:cmi-ejb2:jar:2.1.0:compile 
>    |  |  |  |  |  |  - org.ow2.cmi:cmi-ha:jar:2.1.0:compile 
>    |  |  |  |  |  |     - org.ow2.util:util-cluster-jgroups:jar:1.0.10:compile 
>    |  |  |  |  |  |        - jgroups:jgroups:jar:2.6.5.GA:compile 
>    |  |  |  |  |  - org.ow2.util:util-pool-impl:jar:1.0.10:compile 
>    |  |  |  |  |     +- org.ow2.util:util-xml:jar:1.0.10:compile 
>    |  |  |  |  |     - org.ow2.util:util-scan-api:jar:1.0.10:compile 
>    |  |  |  |  |        - org.ow2.util:util-archive-api:jar:1.0.10:compile 
>    |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.cmi:cmi-core-client:jar:2.1.0:compile 
>    |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.cmi:cmi-core-server:jar:2.1.0:compile 
>    |  |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.util:util-url:jar:1.0.10:compile 
>    |  |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.cmi:cmi-api-server:jar:2.1.0:compile 
>    |  |  |  |  |  - org.ow2.cmi:cmi-components-event:jar:2.1.0:runtime 
>    |  |  |  |  - org.ow2.cmi:cmi-lb:jar:2.1.0:compile 
>    |  |  |  - org.ow2.cmi:cmi-admin:jar:2.1.0:compile 
>    |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.1:compile 
>    |  |  - org.objectweb.howl:howl:jar:1.0.1-1:compile 
>    |  +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.9:compile 
>    |  +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile 
>    |  +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.1:compile 
>    |  |  - javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile 
>    |  +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile 
>    |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.8:compile 
>    |  +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.8:compile 
>    |  |  - commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.5:compile 
>    |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.8:compile 
>    |  |  - org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.3.0:compile 
>    |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:1.6.2:compile 
>    |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.7:compile 
>    |  |  - org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.7:compile 
>    |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.3:compile 
>    |  - commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2:compile 
>    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:2.5.6:compile 
>    |  - commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile 
>    +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:2.5.6:compile 
>    +- org.springframework:spring-hibernate3:jar:2.0.8:compile 
>    |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile 
>    |  +- org.springframework:spring-dao:jar:2.0.8:compile 
>    |  - org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:2.0.8:compile 
>    +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:2.5.6:compile 
>    +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:jar:1.1.1-ea:compile 
>    |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.1:compile 
>    |  |  - stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile 
>    |  - com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.1.12:compile 
>    |     - javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.1:compile 
>    |        - javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile 
>    +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.1.1-ea:compile 
>    +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.1.1-ea:compile 
>    |  - asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile 
>    +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.1.1-ea:compile 
>    +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-spring:jar:1.1.1-ea:compile 
>    |  +- org.springframework:spring:jar:2.5.6:compile 
>    |  - org.springframework:spring-web:jar:2.5.6:compile 
>    +- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1:compile 
>    +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.1_3:compile 
>    +- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1.2:compile 
>    +- org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.2.6.ga:compile 
>    |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.2.3:compile 
>    |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile 
>    |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile 
>    |  - commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.1.1:compile 
>    +- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:1.8.4:compile 
>    |  - org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.0:compile 
>    +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-all:jar:5.4.3:compile 
>    +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.13:compile 
>    +- junit:junit:jar:4.4:test 
>    +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:2.5.6:test 
>    +- com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7:compile 
>    |  +- bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:jar:138:compile 
>    |  +- bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:138:compile 
>    |  - org.bouncycastle:bctsp-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile 
>    |     +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile 
>    |     - org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile 
>    +- net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:jar:2.6.12:compile 
>    - net.sf.proguard:proguard:jar:4.3:compile

these are the dependency that include in the war file , please tell me how to update the dependencies because everyone depending on another.
Is there any tool available for it or have to do it manually.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just update the dependencies to Spring and Hibernate, then all transitive dependencies will be updated as well. If you have a dependency to one of the transitive dependencies you might get a version clash, which will give an error upon deploy. Deply-fix-repeat until no more errors, then start functional testing.

Comment: @Tobb i did it in the last year as well , when i was updating Spring 2.5.6 to 3.0.5 , it takes lot of time of mine around 2-3 days then after i didn't even check it that all the functionality is working fine or not but this time , demand is too much , have to update every thing , We use HibernateDaoSupport but in hibernate 4 there is no HibernateDaoSupport ,so need to keep all the changes in mind to update this.

Comment: Yeah, I had the same thing when upgrading to Hibernate 4. It's a bit of a pain, but so worth it to get JPA 2.0 etc. For upgrading HibernateDaoSupport, inject a `SessionFactory`, and change `getSession(false)` with `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`

Comment: Remember to search your config files for dependencies like 
"org.springframework.orm.hibernate3" in sessionFactory.